# Disabling a Button after Validaton of 3 fields without using MVVM (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class named Resolution with properties **Resitem** (string), **Resdate** (DateTime), **Resdetail** (string).

I have a Window with 2 textboxes and a datepicker.

The program reads an xml file into a dataset, converts it to Observable Collection, Can add objects to the Dataset and ObservableCollection and when closing the window it saves everything to the xml file again.

Also it uses IDataErrorInfo to validate the textfields and date and shows a (!) in front of them when an error is found (textbox empty or date in the past)

Everything works fine the only thing I can't figure out how to to without using MVVM is to Disable the Add button untill all values are validated okay and following : when all values are okay and I add them , to clear the fields and put the  datepicker on the current date again.

Any help would be appreciated since the questions i found on StackOverflow concerning this problem aren't exactly the ones i need.

If code snippets are needed , shoot.

Comment: What you mean by "without MVVM"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainWindow xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow"
            Height="350"
            Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=InputData.SomeInput,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="SaveButton"  Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}">Start</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Here the code behind of the **MainWindow**:

```
 public partial class MainWindow

    {
        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
        public MyInputData InputData { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InputData = new MyInputData();
            SaveCommand = new MyCommand(InputData, ExecuteAction);
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += (s, a) => { DataContext = this; }; 
        }

        private void ExecuteAction()
        {
            //do save
        }
    }
```

**MyInputData** class:

```
public class MyInputData
        : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public string SomeInput { get; set; }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;

                if (columnName == "SomeInput")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeInput))
                        result = "Please enter a Input Data";
                }

                Error = result;
                return result;
            }
        }

        public string Error { get; private set; }
    }
```

**MyCommand** implementation:

```
public class MyCommand 
           : ICommand
    {
        private readonly IDataErrorInfo _dataErrorInfo;
        private readonly Action _action;

        public MyCommand(IDataErrorInfo dataErrorInfo, Action action)
        {
            _dataErrorInfo = dataErrorInfo;
            _action = action;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dataErrorInfo.Error);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action.Invoke();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would usually do was to add A command to the Button first!

Then inside the commands **CanExecute** event handler (in code behind) I would check if everything is set...

In your case that would be checking for the value of Error property of models/viewmodels you used for binding.

```
private void Save_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = Model.Error == "";
    }
```

if you need more help or another approach, I ask you to specify why this approach is not helpful or what you are actually trying to accomplish.